# How might I programmatically lock a folder on an Android SD card?

Tags: android

How might I programmatically lock a folder (with a username and password) on an Android SD card?

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

External storage such as the SD card has no permissions associated with it. The closest you could come is to store your data in some encrypted form that requires a password to decrypt.

Comment: ok thanks..  how we can make encryption on the sd-card folder and make decryption.. i mean can you pl give me any example related to that???.